# Navigation app that works with the Task Pinning API?

Tags: android, navigation

Google's turn-by-turn navigation on Android is incompatible with the new [task pinning API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html) because the [launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) of the navigation activity is set to launch it in a new task.

Is there a third-party turn-by-turn navigation app that can be launched with an implicit intent **and** can be launched into the current task?

Comment: Never heard the term. Do you know whether that might require a specific permission (to be recognized by that)? I have a list for [Navigation apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_navigation), maybe that can give you some pointers at least (while waiting for good answers).

Comment: It has to do with how the activities are declared in the navigation app's manifest.  Google Maps seems to use the "singleTask" mode described in my link.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Kevin! Looks interesting (like one could "push in a waypoint" into the currently open map view, or "flash a pointer 'go there'", if I got *the idea* correctly). Pretty new (Lollipop, which I don't have yet on any of my devices – hence I didn't know). Good luck! Btw: If there is none yet, the dev of Locus Maps is quite responsive usually ;)